# Parsing NTFS Partition in C

Tags: c, windows-xp, ntfs

I'm just a beginner and I have a need to parse a NTFS partition for the purpose of extracting Security Descriptors. (I been trying to use the native functions of the Windows API, but my conclusion is that something is seriously wrong with the functions' behavior, or their documentation.)

I was wondering if anybody here experienced with such requirement, and could give me few hints, references, guidance... where to begin?

(I've found www.ntfs.com, seems to have NTFS structure information, but I'm afraid I'll need something more to get started...)

My intention is to use it under Windows XP.

Comment: As many people use the Windows API successfully I would suggest that you are not understanding the documentation and I would suggest you show us the code that you have so that we can make the documentation clearer.

Comment: @Mark: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845606/msdn-remark-regards-security-descriptors

Are you able to decrypt such vague Remark?

Here's a sample code of my attempt:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814193/re-storing-a-ntfs-security-descriptor-in-c

Comment: I would guess only the 4 SECURITY_INFORMATION values listed in GetNamedSecurityInfo make sense with that function the others only can be used with the Set function (and for consistency the list is only in one place - the Get function where the difference matters)

Comment: So you're suggesting GetNamedSecurityInfo simply can't extract the whole descriptor, therefore I can't re-assign it identically?

(As you noticed, my sample is actually using GetSecurityInfo() , I already tried to use GetNamedSecurityInfo - which gave the same results.)

So my conclusion is accurate? The API can't do my requirement?

Comment: I think, "[NTFS Forensics: A Programmers View of Raw Filesystem Data Extraction](http://grayscale-research.org/new/pdfs/NTFS%20forensics.pdf)" can be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some pretty low-level documentation:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/linux-ntfs/files/NTFS%20Documentation/

Also, have you looked at Microsoft's technical reference for NTFS?:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758691(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, apparently I'm far away from accomplishing it, and I got to the conclusion that the native API behavior simply can't accomplish my requirement with said conditions.

I suppose I'll have to re-think it.

Answer (score 0):

Otherway to start with linux based open source NTFS projects like [linux-ntfs](http://www.linux-ntfs.org/doku.php) or [captive](http://www.jankratochvil.net/project/captive/CVS.pm#source) or [NTFS-3G](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-download/) . That will give you some idea about NTFS read/write operations

Comment: @UK: Thanks for your references. If anybody have further resources for a beginner to get a clearer picture of things... I will appreciate them.